# Set up ELM327 to behave like FTDI - just forwarding commands without OBD init

Tags: ftdi, obd-ii, elm327

My first question on here so I'm not sure if that's the right forum.
I've connected with my car's ECU K-Line through FTDI-OBD cable and terminal. Found it's something like KWP2000 but  without preinit hassle. I just send it commands on 9600 baud, even parity, 1 bit stop and got a reply with VIN number. When I try to send same command with ELM327 it doesn't work and I believe because of ELM adding something, either initialisation of the KWP or adding some checksum or additional info and it doesn't work.
I've already tried using
ATSP5
ATIB96
ATBI

And it still doesn't respond eg. VIN message from sending same command.
My point is to get to secret sensors data from $21 because there is a little info in regular Mode01. And I want to use ELM327 because I wanted to use Android phone to display the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It looks like you're trying to work with some sort of electronics kit that I have no experience with, so I can't help there, but I do think you should probably remove the `elm` tag as on this Q&A site about software development that tag is related to the Elm programming language. This means poor souls like myself are very confused by your question when it pops up in their feed of new Elm language questions!

Comment: This seems to be a pretty specialized question with regards to OBD2, you might have more luck at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com. Then again, I'm not sure whether the ELM327 can be put into this mode at all.